# how to stop repeating nested foreach loop in php

Tags: php, foreach

I have two nested `foreach` loop, now the problem is values is repeating every time when loop execute. I want one time values in `foreach` loop.

i have two table one for product and other for other product where product id is the relation field. now i want to print all the the product in checkbox form and on edit page i want to checked those checkboxes which user have checked when user add them

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('aqeel', 'naseem', 'umer');
$arr2 = array('farooq', 'tahir', 'zaheer');

foreach($arr1 as $one)
{
    echo $one.'<br />';
    foreach($arr2 as $two)
    {
        echo ($two).'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

In the above code, every time `$one` value is added with `$two` value, I want both loop execute their values one time, don't repeat values

following is my real example code where i have nested foreach repeating issue

```
<label for="other_product">Other Product</label>
        <?php 
            $allproducts = $this->product_model->allProducts();
            if($allproducts)
            {
            foreach($allproducts as $allproduct)
            {
                $otherprod_ids = $this->product_model->otherprodids();
                foreach($otherprod_ids as $otherprod_id)
                {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="otherprod_id[]" value="<?=$allproduct->id?>" style="margin-bottom:10px;" /><span style="font-weight:bold; margin:0px 0px 5px 10px;"><?=$allproduct->product_name?></span><br />
        <?php } } }  ?>
```

given below is the output of nested repeating foreach

```
<label for="other_product">Other Product</label>
```

Banners

Banners

Banners

Banners

Banners

Folders

Folders

Folders

Folders

Folders

Letterheads

Letterheads

Letterheads

Letterheads

Letterheads

Bookmarks

Bookmarks

Bookmarks

Bookmarks

Bookmarks

Vinyl Banners

Vinyl Banners

Vinyl Banners

Vinyl Banners

Vinyl Banners

Booklets

Booklets

Booklets

Booklets

Booklets

Brochures

Brochures

Brochures

Brochures

Brochures

Business Cards

Business Cards

Business Cards

Business Cards

Business Cards

Catalogs

Catalogs

Catalogs

Catalogs

Catalogs

Flyers

Flyers

Flyers

Flyers

Flyers

Greeting Cards

Greeting Cards

Greeting Cards

Greeting Cards

Greeting Cards

Labels

Labels

Labels

Labels

Labels

Posters

Posters

Posters

Posters

Posters

Stickers

Stickers

Stickers

Stickers

Stickers

Carbonless Forms

Carbonless Forms

Carbonless Forms

Carbonless Forms

Carbonless Forms

Packaging Boxes

Packaging Boxes

Packaging Boxes

Packaging Boxes

Packaging Boxes

Envelopes

Envelopes

Envelopes

Envelopes

Envelopes

Manuals

Manuals

Manuals

Manuals

Manuals

Newsletters

Newsletters

Newsletters

Newsletters

Newsletters

Rack Cards

Rack Cards

Rack Cards

Rack Cards

Rack Cards

Tags

Tags

Tags

Tags

Tags

Tickets

Tickets

Tickets

Tickets

Tickets

Clings

Clings

Clings

Clings

Clings

CD Jackets

CD Jackets

CD Jackets

CD Jackets

CD Jackets

Comment: please add your expected output

Answer (score 1):

If your expected output is:

```
aqueel
farooq
naseem
tahir
amer
zaheer
```

Your code would look like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < max(count($arr1),count($arr2)); $i++) {
    if ($i < sizeof($arr1))
        echo $arr1[$i]."<br />";
    if ($i < sizeof($arr2))
        echo $arr2[$i]."<br />";
}
```